# Spray: Overriding functions in Traits

Tags: scala, spray

I'm using Spray and have a Base Route trait which defines a number of functions that should be implemented...

```
trait ServiceBaseRoute extends HttpService {
  def function1():Type
  def function2():Type

  lazy val serviceBaseRoute = ...
```

I then mixin this trait to a number of other traits...

```
trait MyRoute1 extends HttpService
  with ServiceBaseRoute {
  override def function1():Type = {...}
  override def function2():Type = {...}

  val myRoute1 = serviceBaseRoute
```

and...

```
trait MyRoute2 extends HttpService
  with ServiceBaseRoute {
  override def function1():Type = {...}
  override def function2():Type = {...}

  val myRoute2 = serviceBaseRoute
```

Finally I construct the top level of the route as follows...

```
trait V1Routes extends HttpService
  with MyRoute1
  with MyRoute2 {

  val v1Routes = 
    pathPrefix("v1") {
      authenticate(...) {
        myRoute1 ~ myRoute2
      }
    }
```

Compiles fine etc... However when I run this the function overrides of MyRoute2 override those defined in MyRoute1. I am thinking this is because I don't have actual instances of MyRoute1 and MyRoute2 as they are being simply mixed in and since MyRoute2 is added in after MyRoute1 its values overwrite those of MyRoute1?
So what would be the best way to implement this preserving the overrides defined in each trait? 
Do I need to define MyRoute1 and MyRoute2 as objects instead?

Thanks

Comment: `serviceBaseRoute` doesn't seem to get used anywhere? Is it used in both `myRoute1` and `myRoute2`?

Comment: Sorry! I've edited it to show where it is used... val myRoute1 = serviceBaseRoute... Essentially both routes contain similar logic but the function overrides define where each route is different and the service base route calls those overridden functions.

Comment: The more I think about this the more I realise it is just badly designed. Of course the functions get overridden when mixing it as traits...

Comment: But how should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, the aim is to have distinct routes in MyRoute1 and MyRoute2, where each is created by customizing serviceBaseRoute. Since ServiceBaseRoute is customized by two functions, you could make serviceBaseRoute a higher order function and pass the implementations of the two functions to it in the sub traits:

```
trait ServiceBaseRoute extends HttpService {

  def serviceBaseRoute(f1: () => Type, f2: () => Type)= ???
}

trait MyRoute1 extends HttpService
with ServiceBaseRoute {

  def f1ImplA(): Type = ???

  def f2ImplA(): Type = ???

  val myRoute1 = serviceBaseRoute(f1ImplA, f2ImplA)
}

trait MyRoute2 extends HttpService
with ServiceBaseRoute {

  def f1ImplB(): Type = ???

  def f2ImplB(): Type = ???

  val myRoute2 = serviceBaseRoute(f1ImplB, f2ImplB)
}

trait V1Routes extends HttpService
with MyRoute1
with MyRoute2 {

  val v1Routes =
    pathPrefix("v1") {
      authenticate(...)
      {
        myRoute1 ~ myRoute2
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still presents problems for me. When you mixin the two routes (MyRoute1 & MyRoute2) into V1Route the compiler complains that there are conflicting method name with f1Impl() and f2Impl() declared in both traits. This seems to be the diamond problem... I also originally wanted to declare these methods as abstract in the base route class so that they have to be implemented when extending the traits. However doing this and using override in the extending class just leads to one of the declarations being used. Like I said maybe this is just a case of bad design?

Comment: It's laziness on my part that they have the same name, they don't need to (and shouldn't for the reason you highlight). My idea is that Since `serviceBaseRoute` needs to be implemented to satisfy the `ServiceBaseRoute` trait, and since the subtraits wish to call this method, they are forced to provide implementations fitting the functions which `serviceBaseRoute` requires.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Thanks!